# How can we use horizontal scrollbar in Windows Forms in C#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, scroll

I'm working on a Windows Forms app. I have a form that I want to add a horizontal scroll to.

Actually I have 10 pictures in my form and users can see 6 pictures together at one time, I want to scroll just the pictures in my form.

Comment: if your form is larger than the screen they cme automatically

Comment: Usability note: horizontal scrolling can be difficult to use. Most mouse products have a wheel that will do vertical scrolling, but the canvases on which controls are placed don't always support wheel-based scrolling. Comparatively fewer have the horizontal scrolling feature on the wheel, and it's a different manner of input that's not as easy to control. Furthermore, applications inconsistently support Shift+wheel to scroll horizontally (Excel also requires Ctrl), making it confusing for users. Moving the mouse to a scroll bar is time wasted. In short, avoid horizontal scrolling at all costs.

Comment: You may probably want to add the Controls that show the images to a FlowLayoutPanel, where auto-scroll is enabled

Comment: You mention to display a bunch of pictures. For that, I wouldn't actually use scrolling but something like a "carussel" component, where you'd move the images left or right by either clicking a button or use left/right arrow key ... like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283025/Simple-Carousel-Control-for-Windows-Forms